# similarity measures in vector space model

Tags: tf-idf, cosine-similarity, vector-space

If I have two vectors represent two sentences contains Tf-IDF weights as following:

v1 = [0.23,0.44,0.95,0.13]

v2 = [0.73,0.04,0.85,0.13]

The traditional (scientific) measure is cosine similarity to measure similarity between them, are there other similarity measures can be used instead?